# Spring Framework Web page development (Java)

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven

So i have some problems and some questions:

**1.** I have installed `Tomcat7`, i configured it in `Eclipse` it works fine when i create `Dynamic Web Project`, with `Dynamic Web Module 2.4`, but it doesn't work fine when i set it to `3.0`, also when i create `Spring Project->Simple Spring Web Maven` template, i am getting error:

```
org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 15
```

**2.** Anyone can give me some direction where to learn about all these compatibility versions of `Tomcat`, `Maven`, `Spring Framework`

**3.** Where to find good examples of Web development using Spring, i have found some, but this compatibility issues and configurations setups fried my brain...

**4.** I found nowhere how to download only `jars` for `Spring Framework`, all i get is some project source files...

Comment: Can you add the line above your `ClassFormatException`. Maybe the same problem as [this one](http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/Problem-when-mvn-site-site-Generating-quot-Dependencies-quot-report-td113470.html)

Comment: http://pastebin.com/BprnPdpc here...

Comment: Ok that does not help. Do you have Groovy as dependency in your Project? https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53735. You can get the dependencies of your Project in Eclipse by opening the pom and selecting the Depency Tab or in a Terminal using maven by `mvm dependency:tree` in your Project folder.

Answer (score 0):

For your question where to download the Spring Artefacts have a look at their [Github Wiki](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Downloading-Spring-artifacts) section "Manually downloading Spring Distributions"

> If for whatever reason you are not using a build system with dependency management capabilities, you can download Spring Framework distribution zips from the Spring repository at http://repo.spring.io.

A tutorial for Web Application Development with Spring you can find on the [Spring IO Page](http://spring.io/guides/tutorials/web/)  or have a look at the [Spring Webflow Project](http://projects.spring.io/spring-webflow/) page there is also a link to Spring Webflow [Sample Projects on Github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-webflow-samples) .

Answer (score 0):

check the below youtube channel, hope it helps you:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aGldP909l6o&list=PL7350712B99EFC5DD